# Trying to write some 'Show/Hide More Text' functionality for para's within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to write some code, or find a plug-in that would a take a couple of dynamically generated paragraphs and show the first 3 lines and hide the rest.

some product pages on Amazon have this type of functionality.

then, via a trigger, allows the user to show more content, and then once opened, hide the content.

the height of the divs and contained p's won't be know because they are generated dynamically. the mark-up might look something like..

```
<div class="hide-show-txt">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor etc. etc……</p>
  <p>Some more lorem ipsum dolor etc. etc……</p>
</div>
<div id="hide-show-user-trigger">
<span>Show More Text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would store the text in a different variable, and then when it is in the "hide" mode, you only display lets say the first 100 characters, then append the "..." to it. When the user clicks on the "show" option, then change the text value or content, to the full string. If you need an example, I can write one for you.

Quick example:

```
  var allText = "all the text is stored like this";

  $("yourDiv:show").on("click", function(){
     $("divContent").text(allText);
  });

  $("yourDiv:hide").on("click", function(){
     var shortstring = allText.subString(0, 150) + "...";
     $("divContent").text(shortString);
  });
```

Simple, but only showing a brief example of how you could manage it. Obviously, please use a better naming scheme.  lol :)

Comment: Surely, if you go down that route, you would just hide the extra text you don't want visible and toggle that and the ellipsis together rather than output duplicate content. EDIT: Ah you took that advice.

Comment: How does this account for font-size, width of the element etc that would all affect the number of lines shown? OP asked for first three lines.

Comment: I wasn't sure off hand, without putting to much thought, on how to toggle certain section of the text. Unless, you put a span tag or something at the point you wanted to hide. Then again, I was going off the assumption, of what if you didn't know the content before hand. But I do like "popnoodles" method, and for his reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/uRmr3/

API: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Rest you can see the behaviour in demo, hope it fits your need `:)`

*Behavior* - Click on chow moretext it will toggle up and down, you can hide it to start with if thats what you are looking for, Like **this demo** => http://jsfiddle.net/b6Sa3/

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hide-show-user-trigger').on('click', function () {

        $(this).prev('div.hide-show-txt').toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery plugin. It has  some nice features.
http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html

Answer (score 1):

By knowing the line-height you can set the height to be equal to 3 lines. Then with some simple jQuery, we can have it change to auto height when read more is clicked.

Heres a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nct6e/

Html:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam viverra, justo in ornare lobortis, tortor dolor tempus nunc, a fermentum dui justo nec tortor. Nunc dapibus auctor accumsan. Nullam faucibus tortor erat, quis ultrices metus tincidunt sagittis. Vestibulum nec urna metus. Phasellus lorem ligula, hendrerit nec magna vel, elementum molestie tortor. In sapien ante, rutrum posuere malesuada ac, mattis a purus. Mauris at diam sem. Praesent ac neque aliquet, pharetra est a, gravida lorem. Cras eget risus velit. Praesent sed tempor orci. Ut eu metus sit amet lectus imperdiet aliquet. Curabitur at leo erat. Mauris magna est, consectetur tincidunt pharetra quis, lobortis eu erat. Phasellus egestas lorem quis augue hendrerit eleifend in ac leo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam ac arcu nec orci rutrum aliquet non at augue.</p>
    <div class="read-more">Read more</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function() {
    var expanded = 0;
    $(".content .read-more").on("click", function() {
        if(expanded == 0) {
            $(this).siblings("p").css("height", "auto");
            $(this).text("Show less");
            expanded = 1;
        } else {
            $(this).siblings("p").css("height", "60");
            $(this).text("Show more");
            expanded = 0;
        }
    })
})();
```

css:

```
.content {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.content p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
}

.content .read-more {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```